# About json and ajax

Tags: ajax, json, facebook

I'm new to ajax. Why can't I just paste this into my URL bar and expect it to make a change to a facebook setting?

```
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/privacy/simple_save.php?id=00000&audience_json={"00000":{"value":"50"}}
```

Comment: Because Facebook expects as POST request maybe …?